# Link is being set to localhost:3000/og.png in production

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm using the dynamic og image feature in the app dir.

Basically, I create a opengraph-image.tsx file and it will autogenerate me an og image.

However, in  production the src of the og image is set to `localhost:3000/og.png` instead of `mywebsite.com/og.png`

Any idea how to fix this? I don't have `localhost:3000` specified anywhere in my project

My code is exactly like the next.js docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/opengraph-image#dynamic-assets---generate-images-with-code

From the docs above, this is the ouput of the opengraph-image.tsx file. The src of the image is being auto generated and I cannot set it myself. I'm not sure how it generates the link.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<generated>" />
```

Answer (score 9):

I had to set metadataBase in my layout page

```
export const metadata = {
  metadataBase: new URL('https://website.com'),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you hosted on Netlify or Vercel? Or elsewhere?

I noticed different behaviors between Netlify and Vercel.

Netlify would only work by exporting a `metadata` object for your page (in my case I put it in root `layout.tsx`), which sounds not ideal for you since want a dynamic og:image.

```
export const metadata = {
  title: "Sphere Showcase",
  description:
    "Showcase of Photosphere, 360, and Panorama images from around the world. Upload and share your own!",
  keywords: ["Photosphere", "360 Photo", "Panorama", "World Map"],
  openGraph: {
    images: 'https://photos.sphereshowcase.com/tBJczsgyzUAP3woETDr31.jpg',
  },
};
```

In Vercel, `opengraph-image.png` worked out of the box. I simply had my image at the highest level of my app and it worked.

I put together two small write-ups showing the different static og:image methods for Netlify and Vercel.

[Static og:image in Netlify for Next.js](https://thetombomb.com/posts/og-image-nextjs-netlify)

[Static og:image in Vercel for Next.js](https://thetombomb.com/posts/og-image-nextjs-vercel)

Answer (score 0):

I use a dynamic solution that works for deployment to different environments:

```
/app/layout.tsx

export async function generateMetadata(): Promise<Metadata> {
  return {
    //
    // dynamically get the host from the Next headers
    metadataBase: new URL(`https://${headers().get("host")}`),
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're facing this issue in AWS Amplify, this has fixed for me.

Create an environment variable: VERCEL_URL , value : hostname (for e.g:- domain.com) without https://)

NextJS 14.1.0